# Why the force is equal to minus the variation of the momentum for a gas particle hitting the wall?

Tags: forces, pressure, ideal-gas

Why when one calculates the force exerted by a gas on the wall we say that the force is equal to (for a single particle ): F = - $\Delta p$ .
But to me , it should be :

$F = (p$<sub>f</sub> $- p$<sub>i</sub> ) $= -p$<sub>i</sub> - $p$<sub>i</sub> = $-2p$<sub>i</sub>.

In this case the direction of force would be on the opposite direction of the wall which is wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in momentum that you are calculating is the change in momentum of the particle. So the force that you are calculating is the force ***on*** the particle. By Newton's third law, the particle applies ***an equal but opposite*** force on the wall, so that ***- sign*** that you are worried about gets reversed and you get force along the ***correct*** direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose one direction for momentum as positive, for example, one towards the wall, then direction away from the wall is negative. Force exerted on the wall is towards the wall so it is positive in our choice. Total change of the momentum of the particle is negative and because you have p towards the wall and then -p away from the wall so you have (-p)-p which is -2p which is total change. Force exerted by this particle is of oposite direction so it is proportional to 2p not -2p.